# pe:documentViewer no work with primefaces 5.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

pe:documentViewer doesn't work with primefaces 5.1. This code works good with PF 5.0, but in PF 5.1 shows this error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: org.primefaces.util.DynamicResourceBuilder.build(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;Z)Ljava/lang/String;
>   Causa Raíz
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.util.DynamicResourceBuilder.build(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;Z)Ljava/lang/String;

Facelets code:

```
<p:dialog  resizable="false" closeOnEscape="true"  appendTo="@(body)" modal="true" id="dialog2" header="Detalles de la factura" widgetVar="servDialog2" width="1000px" height="630px">  
    <pe:documentViewer cache="false" height="600" value="#{listadoFacturasMB.fileDownload}"/>                                            
</p:dialog>
```

> Información:   Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.util.DynamicResourceBuilder.build(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;Z)Ljava/lang/String;
>       at org.primefaces.extensions.component.documentviewer.DocumentViewerRenderer.getDocumentSource(DocumentViewerRenderer.java:116)
>       at org.primefaces.extensions.component.documentviewer.DocumentViewerRenderer.generateSrc(DocumentViewerRenderer.java:49)
>       at org.primefaces.extensions.component.documentviewer.DocumentViewerRenderer.encodeMarkup(DocumentViewerRenderer.java:41)
>       at org.primefaces.extensions.component.documentviewer.DocumentViewerRenderer.encodeEnd(DocumentViewerRenderer.java:27)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:83)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
>       at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeContent(DialogRenderer.java:180)
>       at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeMarkup(DialogRenderer.java:109)
>       at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeEnd(DialogRenderer.java:47)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:83)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
>       at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
>       at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
>       at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
>       at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:79)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:81)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
>       at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Advertencia:   JSF1087: no se puede generar la página de error de Facelets dado que la respuesta ya se ha confirmado.
Grave:   javax.faces.FacesException: org.primefaces.util.DynamicResourceBuilder.build(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;Z)Ljava/lang/String;
javax.faces.FacesException: org.primefaces.util.DynamicResourceBuilder.build(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;Z)Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:141)
    at javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.util.DynamicResourceBuilder.build(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;Z)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.documentviewer.DocumentViewerRenderer.getDocumentSource(DocumentViewerRenderer.java:116)
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.documentviewer.DocumentViewerRenderer.generateSrc(DocumentViewerRenderer.java:49)
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.documentviewer.DocumentViewerRenderer.encodeMarkup(DocumentViewerRenderer.java:41)
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.documentviewer.DocumentViewerRenderer.encodeEnd(DocumentViewerRenderer.java:27)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:83)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeContent(DialogRenderer.java:180)
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeMarkup(DialogRenderer.java:109)
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeEnd(DialogRenderer.java:47)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:83)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:79)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:81)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    ... 29 more

FATAL:   JSF1073: se ha interceptado java.lang.NoSuchMethodError durante el procesamiento de RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Mensaje=org.primefaces.util.DynamicResourceBuilder.build(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;Z)Ljava/lang/String;
FATAL:   org.primefaces.util.DynamicResourceBuilder.build(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;Z)Ljava/lang/String;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.util.DynamicResourceBuilder.build(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;Z)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.documentviewer.DocumentViewerRenderer.getDocumentSource(DocumentViewerRenderer.java:116)
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.documentviewer.DocumentViewerRenderer.generateSrc(DocumentViewerRenderer.java:49)
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.documentviewer.DocumentViewerRenderer.encodeMarkup(DocumentViewerRenderer.java:41)
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.documentviewer.DocumentViewerRenderer.encodeEnd(DocumentViewerRenderer.java:27)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:83)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeContent(DialogRenderer.java:180)
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeMarkup(DialogRenderer.java:109)
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeEnd(DialogRenderer.java:47)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:83)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:79)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:81)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: Can you make sure that `DynamicResourceBuilder#build` method exists in the jar of your class path ?

Comment: Yes, i can, method exists...

Comment: can you post full stack trace ?

Comment: what version of PFE do you use? A compatible one?

Comment: PrimeFaces Ext 3.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade your extensions to PrimeFaces Extensions 3.1.0.

See [Release Notes](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/wiki/Release-Notes)

Answer (score 0):

Try use @SessionScoped in yours class bean listadoFacturasMB instead @ViewScoped